# linux C socket doesn't print within a loop

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, networking

I tried to make a simple server in C.
It works ok. When I added a loop to receive connections the printf() doesn't seem to work.

```
listen(mysocket, 5); 
while (1) {
    consock = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &socksize);
    printf("incoming connection from %s \n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));

    send(consock, message, strlen(message), 0);
    close(consock);      
}

close(mysocket);
```

If I remove the while loop it shows the message in printf function. Nothing prints where there is the loop.

Please tell me how this happens. I think I'm missing something here.

Thank you!

Comment: Buffering issue maybe, especially if your outputting to some file or pipe. Try fflush(stdout) after the printf.

Comment: You shall always check a system call's outcome for error and to do you self a favour log them for example using `perror()`. At least the relevant one's which in the sources you show are: `listen()`, `accept()`, `send()` and `close()`.

Comment: @alk Sure, but it's perfectly acceptable to omit error checking in a bit of sample code.

Comment: @KristofProvost: Absolutly ... - if it's for the sample, and if, it's a good ideat to mentioned they were left out for the sake of readybility...;-)

Comment: Did you close `stdout`? Or somehow redirected it by for example calling `daemon()`.

Comment: closing the stdout works... :)

Comment: Change the code to print to `stderr`, using `fprintf(stderr, ....`.

Comment: stderr also works. what that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding `fflush(stdout);` after printf.

Comment: I've added fflush(stdout); but still not printing. But send() function works. my client receives the message.
But server still not printing it.

Comment: `stdout` is at least line buffered so a `\n` performs an implicit flush.

Comment: when i get a new terminal my original code works. but when the request stashed the stdout seems to be struck. May I add sleep() or some thing?

Answer (score 0):

From the dicussion in the comments to the OP I conclude that somewhere in the code under certain conditons `close(1)` is called, which closes `stdout`.